# How Express Js work as devDependencies of a project

Tags: reactjs, express, vue.js

I'm starting on a project which was developed previously by others. There I've seen 'devDependencies' in 'package.json'. There I've seen that one specific dependency is developed on ExpressJS which makes some request to the server. Now I got confused because ExpressJS is a REST framework in itself and it is running on a specific server '8010' and my Vue/React Project is running in port 8000.

How can a project with its own server(i.e Express in 8010 in node_modules) can run within a project which is running in Port 8000.

Is ExpressJS creating its server in the browser on the fly?

Comment: The server Node / Express is running on a different port and the client on another... what’s the issue exactly? That’s how it should be... Server in the browser???

Comment: I'm not getting the concept of how the Express Project is running inside the Vue/React project because the Express project is inside the node_modules of my Vue/React project.

Comment: Oh... it’s difficult to tell... my guess would be that instead of using the webpack-dev-server they used express...